# Cannot run JAR in browser

Tags: java, jar, signing

I created applet in Eclipse, and it worked well. then I Export it via:

```
Export -> JAR File
```

select all my classes, and select "export generated class and resources"

Then I do theese steps

```
keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias me
keytool -selfcert -keystore myKeyStore -alias me
jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore jarfile.jar me
```

And the I create .html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <applet archive='applet.jar' code='cz.nastup.applet.Window.class' width='1000' height='400'></applet>
</body>

</html>
```

When I tried to run it localy. It gives me:

```
Error decoding percent encided characters
```

When I Tried to run it on server, it gives me:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Please, can someone tell me what have I done wrong ?

Comment: Does `cz.nastup.applet.Window` extend `JApplet`?

Comment: also it have init() start() stop() destroy() methods and As I said, it runs perfectly in eclipse

Comment: What version of Java is this for?

Comment: Are you running with high security settings? See also the release notes for [7u51](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html), specifically *Block Self-Signed and Unsigned applets on High Security Setting*.

Comment: No I have settings on minumum

Comment: I just found out that it worked on FireFox but in Chrome Im getting the first error (Error decoding...)